# Xcode: Project in Project

Tags: xcode, project

I made my main project in Xcode, but I need add additional project there. 
I created it, but if I try connect headers from the additional project, I get a "file not found" error.
How can I fix it?

Screenshot of the project:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build static library (.a files) with sub-projects, and set the `User Header Search Paths` in your Main Project.

FYI:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/

http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-xcode-static-library-subprojects-and-submodules

Comment: But if I create static library, I can't update it without re-compile library.